# Magento2 Installation error - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING or '('

Tags: magento2, error, installation

I have been trying to install the Magento 2 framework ahead of the upcoming webinar but I have been getting errors.

Has anyone been able to install via CLI or the web UI?

Here is the error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING or '(' in /home/magento2/dev/shell/run_data_fixtures.php on line 25'`

And here is line 25

`use Magento\Framework\App\State as AppState;`

I've downloaded directly from the GitHub repo and haven't made any code changes yet!

Comment: What php version do you use?

Comment: Hi @Marius Just checked I am using `PHP 5.2.17 `

Comment: Hi @Marius Just checked using `php -v` I am using `PHP 5.2.17 ` but when I run the installer in the browser (readiness check) it shows `Your PHP version is correct (5.4.17).`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is related to a pre release version of Magento 2, more info here: http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/907/magento-2-questions-tagged-beta-alpha-pre-alpha-etc-quo-vadis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams that you have 2 different php versions.
5.4.17 for "browser mode"  and `5.2.17` for command line.
While running the install process the file `dev/shell/run_data_fixtures.php` is called via command line. Look at the method `Magento\Setup\Model\Installer::installDataFixtures`.
PHP `5.2` cannot use namespaces.
Namespaces are available starting `5.3`.
SO you need to upgrade your CLI version of php to `5.4`. This is the minimum supported version for magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

I had to run the following from the CLI inside the setup folder:

1. `cd setup`
2. Run the following:

`php55 -f index.php install --cleanup_database --db_host=localhost --db_name=magento_2 --db_user="username" --db_pass="password" --backend_frontname=admin --base_url=http://domainname/ --language=en_US --timezone=Europe/London --currency=GBP --admin_lastname=LastName --admin_firstname=FirstName --admin_email=email@email.co.uk --admin_username=admin --admin_password=admin_password --use_secure=0`